# Filter 2d list by another 2d list

Tags: python, list, optimization

I have a list **A**:

```
A = [['512', '102']
['410', '105']
['820', '520']]
```

And list **B**:

```
B = [['510', '490', '512', '912']
['512', '108', '102', '520' , '901', '821']
['510', '118', '284']]
```

I would like to leave only these rows in list **A**, that all values of which are contained in at least one row from list **B**.
So my expected output is:

```
[['512', '102']]
```

Because values **'512'** and **'102'** are in second row of list **B**.

I know how to achieve that by iterating or every item in list **A** and compare with every element in list B but the problem is that I have **~500000** rows in list **A** and **~10000** rows in list **B** and it is extremely slow.

Is there a way to achieve that in a more optimal way?

Comment: What if you sorted the lists, this way you wouldn't have to loop through the entire lists every time? I see they're strings but do they have to be?

Comment: Can you convert the lists to sets? Does duplication matter? Are the values in need to be in same list in B (for example 512 and 102, can they be in different lists in B?)

Comment: list `A` will always have 2 elements ? and list `B` has any max , min criteria?

Comment: @goalie1998 They have to be strings, that data was just an example

Comment: @Aaron_ab Yes, I can convert it into set. Duplication doesn't matter. Values from A list need to be in same list in B. Example: if 512 is only in second row of B and 102 is only in third row of B then ['512', '102'] won't be in output

Comment: @Naveen Not always, row from A list can have from 2 to ~300 elements but always this number is the same for all rows in A list (in B list number of elements in rows can be different)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must definitely work with sets here, as they are much faster than lists.

Here is one solution:

```
[i for i in A if any(set(i)-set(k)==set() for k in B)]
```

result

```
[['512', '102']]
```

Explanation:

`set(i)-set(k)==set()`

checks if all items of i are included in k

`any(set(i)-set(k)==set() for k in B)`

checks if the above is valid for any item of B for specific item of A and finally

`[i for i in A if any(set(i)-set(k)==set() for k in B)]`

returns all items of A that satisfy the above condition

Answer (score 1):

You can make list `B` as a set of all the items uniquely and then check if each list in the `A` list have all items in the `set_B`

```
set_B= {item for sublist in B for item in sublist}
print([i for i in A if len(set(i).difference(set_B)) == 0])
```

Output

```
[['512', '102']]
```

Comment: All elements form list need to be in any row of list B, not in entire list B

Answer (score 1):

I was curious so I ran the code to test, and ended up with a surprising result. Another option is to use this code (if you have only 2 numbers in each row of `A`):

```
for num1, num2 in A:
  for b1 in B:
    if num1 in b1:
      for b2 in B:
        if num2 in b2:
          result.append([num1, num2])
          break
      break
```

I tested this against the set + list comprehension way in the answer by @IoaTzimas like so:

```
import timeit

a = '''for num1, num2 in A:
  for b in B:
    if num1 in b and num2 in b:
      result.append([num1, num2])
      break'''

b = '[i for i in A if any(set(i)-set(k)==set() for k in B)]'


print(min(timeit.Timer(a, setup = '''A = [['512', '102'],
['410', '105'],
['820', '520']]

B = [['510', '490', '512', '912'],
['512', '108', '102', '520' , '901', '821'],
['510', '118', '284']]
result = []''').repeat(100,10000)))


print(min(timeit.Timer(b, setup = '''A = [['512', '102'],
['410', '105'],
['820', '520']]

B = [['510', '490', '512', '912'],
['512', '108', '102', '520' , '901', '821'],
['510', '118', '284']]''').repeat(100,10000)))
```

And the result printed was:

```
0.010839237002073787
0.05843622000247706
```

This indicates that the set method could be a fair bit slower (the times are in seconds) than the for loop method. Your mileage may vary though: it depends on data set and time of day undoubtedly. But it's worth a try if the set method is taking too long.

Comment: We can have more than 2 elements in each row of list A, but this number always be the same for all rows

Comment: In fact, my solution could become way much faster if i get the sets outside the list comprehension. My current solution calculates each set multiple times (per each iteration) and it is not so efficient regarding time